# Reusing function that counts characters in input field

Tags: jquery, forms, input, keypress

In my application I have a lot of forms that I want to validate. For example when you put in a title for an image you can type 10 character, and how many characters that is left is shown next to the field.

The functions works fine, however I want to use it for a lot of input fields in different forms, that has different classes and/or id's. Below is the functions (i'm using one with keyup that updates the number of characters left if you hit backspace, because that doesn't seem to work with keypress).

So, how can I reuse these functions for input fields with different class (or id) names?

```
    $('.imageTitle').keypress(function(e) {
        var value = $(this).val(),
            valueLength = value.length;
            set = 15,
            remain = parseInt(set - valueLength);

        if (remain <= 0 && e.which !== 0 && e.charCode !== 0) {
            $('.imageTitle').val((value).substring(0, valueLength - 1));
        }

        $('#titleCharsLeft').html('&nbsp; ' + remain + ' left');
    });

    $('.imageTitle').keyup(function(e) {

        var value = $(this).val(),
            valueLength = value.length;
            set = 15,
            remain = parseInt(set - valueLength);

        if (e.keyCode == 8) {
            $('.imageTitle').val((value).substring(0, valueLength - 1));
        }

        $('#titleCharsLeft').html('&nbsp; ' + remain + ' left');
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternate demo that provides some customization and non repetitive code by making the delegate a function.  Without actually making a plugin this is an alternate approach.

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/effAF/2/

HTML: You will notice I've added a data-length attribute to control each individual input's length.

```
<div id="titleCharsLeft"></div>

<form>
    <input type="text" class="validateThis" data-length="10" />
    <input type="text" class="validateThis" data-length="15" />
    <input type="text" class="validateThis" data-length="10" />
    <input type="text" class="validateThis" data-length="10" />
</form>​
```

JS: I've made a function that is being called in the events as well as changing to `on`.

```
function validateLength(el) {
    console.log('hit');
    var $this = $(el);
    var value = $this.val(),
        valueLength = value.length;
        set = parseInt($this.attr('data-length'));
        remain = parseInt(set - valueLength);

    if (remain <= 0 && e.which !== 0 && e.charCode !== 0) {
        $('.imageTitle').val((value).substring(0, valueLength - 1));
    }

    $('#titleCharsLeft').html('&nbsp; ' + remain + ' left');
}

$(document).on( 'keypress','input.validateThis',function(e){
     validateLength(this);
});

$(document).on( 'keyup', 'input.validateThis',function(e){
     validateLength(this);
});
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding a common class to each of the input fields you wish to validate against and then applying a $.delegate() like this:

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input class="validateThis" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).delegate('input.validateThis', 'keypress', function(e){
    ...
});

$(document).delegate('input.validateThis', 'keyup', function(e){
    ...
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/kGfqJ/1/)**

I hope this helps!

Comment: @holyredbeard Disregard my previous comment, had it right.. need coffee :) Added a demo.